# multiTouch в Instrumented Test

Tags: android, test-automation

Как в инструментальном тесте нажать и удерживать две кнопки?
Если делать так:

```
onView(withId(R.id.btnKey1)).perform(pressAndHold());
onView(withId(R.id.btnKey2)).perform(pressAndHold());
```

то в `onTouch()` получаю такой результат:

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN btnKey1
MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL btnKey1
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN btnKey2
```

происходит нажатие первой кнопки `btnKey1`, при вызове `btnKey2` первая кнопка получает `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` (как я понимаю, выход за границу `view`) и нажатие второй. Как следствие не могу получить `ACTION_UP` для `btnKey1`.

```
    @Override
    public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
        if(viewKeyDrv1 == null){
            viewKeyDrv1 = view;
            float[] precision = Press.FINGER.describePrecision();
            float[] coords = GeneralLocation.CENTER.calculateCoordinates(view);
            sMotionEventDownKeyDrv1 = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController, coords, precision).down;
        }
        else{
            if(viewKeyDrv1 == view) {
                if (sMotionEventDownKeyDrv1 != null) {
                    throw new AssertionError("sMotionEventDownKeyDrv1 down");
                }
            }
            else{
                if(viewKeyDrv2 == null){
                    viewKeyDrv2 = view;
                    float[] precision = Press.FINGER.describePrecision();
                    float[] coords = GeneralLocation.CENTER.calculateCoordinates(view);
                    sMotionEventDownKeyDrv2 = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController, coords, precision).down;
                }
                else {
                    if(viewKeyDrv2 == view) {
                        if (sMotionEventDownKeyDrv2 != null) {
                            throw new AssertionError("sMotionEventDownKeyDrv2 down");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение:

```
 @Test
 public void test_RunAll() {
     final GraFixActivity activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
     TouchDown(activity, R.id.btnKey1);
     TouchDown(activity, R.id.btnKey2);
     TouchUp(activity, R.id.btnKey1);
     TouchUp(activity, R.id.btnKey2);
}

synchronized public static void TouchDown(final GraFixActivity activity, final int Id) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View view = activity.findViewById(Id);
            float[] flocation = GeneralLocation.CENTER.calculateCoordinates(view);
            long uptimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain( uptimeMillis, uptimeMillis, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, flocation[0], flocation[1], 0);
            view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            event.recycle();
        }
    });
}
```

Не совсем по фэншую, но тестить как то надо...)